# Problems with variable assignment (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def bet(sport,home,away,market,selection,odds,stake,profit,bookie,tipster=None):
    global df
    if profit > 0:
        is_won = True
    elif profit < 0:
        is_won = False
    elif profit == 0:
        None
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[sport,home,away,market,selection,odds,tipster,stake,is_won,profit,bookie]], columns=columns_list)
    df = df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
    if profit > 0:
        print("Good bet on %s! :)" %selection)
    elif profit < 0:
        if tipster is not None:
            print("Don't trust %s! :(" %tipster)
        elif tipster is None:
            print("Shame...")
    elif profit == 0:
        print("Cowboys")
```

This is returning UnboundLocalError: local variable 'is_won' referenced before assignment

Comment: When `profit == 0` is true, `is_won` is not defined. Set it to a default value and the error should go away.

Comment: Well, if profit is 0 the is_won is not defined. But you use it in `temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[sport,home,away,market,selection,odds,tipster,stake,is_won,profit,bookie]], columns=columns_list)`

Comment: of course, so dumb of me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when `profit == 0`. In this case, `is_won` will not be defined. Also, your indentation is messed up.